# Can javascript for loop starts from negative number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

Here is a standard `for` loop:

```
for (i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    el.append('<span>' + i + '</span>');
}
```

This should append 11 spans with text from -5 up to 5, but this doesn't work at all...

```
for (i=-5; i<=5; i++) {
    el.append('<span>' + i + '</span>');
}
```

Is it possible to start from `i = -5`, for example?

---

During creating Fiddle found misspell... `i+= -5`

Sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you explain what "doesn't work" means, exactly?

Comment: It does work. What error are you getting?

Comment: int's are signed by default so yes, perfectly possible.

Comment: I'll try to make jsfiddle with some example...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahL7uoj2/

Comment: Not sure why folks are voting to close. The question includes a snippet of code, states that it doesn't seem to be working, and asks if it *could be valid*. Including the specific error won't change the legality of the snippet. It's not a great question and could be phrased better, but is asking if some syntax is valid and includes an example.

Comment: @ssube "Why isn't this code working".... I have no idea - it should, based on what we've been told.  It's the perfect close vote reason.

Comment: @ssube — The question doesn't include sufficient code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JamesThorpe The question isn't "why isn't the code working", it's "is this code allowed?" The last line is *very* clear on that: "Question is is it possible to start from i = -5, for example?"

Comment: "This should append 11 spans with text from -5 up to 5, but this doesn't work at all..."

Comment: @Quentin Nowhere in the question does the OP ask us to fix the code, only whether that syntax is allowed in JS.

Comment: @ssube If you read the question behind the quesiton, the OP is only asking that question because they have a snippet of code that they say is giving them an error.

Comment: @JamesThorpe If the OP wants to ask whether some code is valid, so they can go debug the problem on their own, that's totally a good thing.

Comment: "this doesn't work at all" is not a problem description. Anyway, most likely the problem lies within `el`, it is not a jQuery object I guess.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and it works fine.

```
for (i=-5; i<=5; i++) {
   ...
}
```

is the same thing as

```
i=-5;
while (i<=5) {
   ...
   i++;
}
```

(Except the `i++` is executed even if `continue` is used.)

The point is that any expression is allowed inside the `for`'s first part.

Comment: If the code in the question works fine, then you aren't solving the problem, you just can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Quentin, Again, there is no problem. The question is "is it possible?" The answer is "yes", and I showed him how.

Comment: You are taking too literal a reading of the question and not paying attention to the context. It says "this doesn't work at all", makes the assumption that it is because of the negative numbers, and then asks for confirmation. The real question is how to make that code work.

Comment: @Quentin, *You* are taking it too literal. "This doesn't work at all" is not a problem definition. I can't answer a question he didn't ask, only the one he did ask. If he edits his Question to actually include a question other than the one he currently asks, I'll be happy to edit my answer. But if he has a second question, he should really post a second Question.

Comment: @Quentin, Besides, you are mistaken. It's not a case of being unable to reproduce; it's a case of the OP being mistaken. "This doesn't work at all" is wrong. It works at least in part. And the part the OP specifically thought was broken is that part that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Loops are simply made up of three expressions, each of which is executed at a particular time during the loop's iteration. There are no real restrictions on what the expressions can or cannot do, although the second one should typically return a boolean.

The first expression is executed when the loop is first hit and is meant to initialize variables. The most common example is `i = 0`, but you can do almost anything (`i = 'a'` works just as well, or `counter.reset()`).

The second expression is executed before each iteration and, if it returns false, will prevent the loop from running again. The most common example is `i < n`, but you can use `i.length < n` or `counter.done()`.

The third expression is executed each iteration and intended to modify some counter that will eventually stop the loop. The most common example is `++i`, but you can use `i = i + 'a'` or `counter.next()`.

All of these are valid loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }
for (var i = 'a'; i.length < 10; i = i + 'a') { ... }
for (counter.reset(); counter.done(); counter.next()) { ... }
```